# Get the number of indexed URLs there are for a domain on Google via Google Sheets

Tags: seo, search-results, google-index, api

I want pull the number of indexed results for a URL on Google into Google Sheets.

Some methods that others in the SEO community have reported to **not** work are:

- IMPORTXML and the XPATH for the class that shows how many results for a URL
- URLFetchApp.Fetch / Regex and IMPORTFROMWEB (add on)

Specifically, I'm looking for the number of indexed URLs there are for a CELL reference.

I found [this](https://www.connecthitech.com/how-to-check-multiple-urls-or-pages-has-been-indexed-in-google-by-using-google-sheet/) article that does it *from within* Google sheets like this:

```js
function isPageIndexed(url)
{
   url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=site:"+url;
      var options = {
     'muteHttpExceptions': true,
     'followRedirects': false
   };
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
   var html     = response.getContentText();
   if (html.match(/Your search -.*- did not match any documents./) ){
     return "URL is Not Indexed";
   }
   else {
     return "URL is Indexed";
   }
}
```

However, they go on to say:

> First test this for very few urls. If you want to test multiple urls means the best option is use proxy.

Quite literally half the purpose of doing this in a spreadsheet would be to get multiple results.

That being said, if I'd be inclined to do this via the [Google Search Console API](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original). I'm skeptical as to why others have taken a scraping approach if GSC has an API and the Coverage data exists (amongst many other data that might be desired in Sheets).

Please let me know in the comments if I can clarify anything.

Comment: Site searches on Google don't give accurate results counts. What are you playing to use this data for?

Comment: I'm sorry Mike, I must be missing something.  Isn't this built into Google Search Console already?  You just have to combine the sheets for Covered>Indexed, Not Submitted in Sitemap and Coverage>Submitted and Indexed.